# What is the origin of ZLIB's "Zlib error -2 deflating data"

Tags: apache-2.2, php-fpm, php7

Some of my sites are getting, seemingly without reason, strange errors like these:

`[Fri Nov 06 08:29:07.677505 2020] [deflate:error] [pid 23820:tid 140019129566976] [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX] AH01386: Zlib error -2 deflating data ((null)), referer: https://www.XXX.XXX/XXX`

These errors happen on seemingly random pages, and can be fixed by updating the source code with a comment even. Every change seems to fix this, but the error keeps popping up.

**What I've tried**

After reading this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37952355/zlib-z-stream-error-deflating-data-in-apache-error-log, we have tried migrating the website to another server, updating the zlib library, using a newer server os (debian), using another php version (currently on 7.4). There is nothing in the code that is using (g)zip functionality. There is also nothing in the .htaccess except redirects.

Some info from the phpinfo:

```
Configure command:
'./configure' '--enable-embed' '--prefix=/usr/local/php74' '--program-suffix=74' '--enable-fpm' '--with-fpm-systemd' '--enable-litespeed' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/php74/lib/php.conf.d' '--with-curl' '--enable-gd' '--with-gettext' '--with-jpeg' '--with-freetype' '--with-kerberos' '--with-openssl' '--with-mhash' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' '--with-mysqli=mysqlnd' '--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd' '--with-pear' '--with-sodium=/usr/local' '--with-webp' '--with-xsl' '--with-zlib' '--with-zip' '--with-iconv=/usr/local' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-sockets' '--enable-soap' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-intl' 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/icu/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig'

ZLIB:
ZLib Support        enabled
Stream Wrapper      compress.zlib://
Stream Filter       zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
Compiled Version    1.2.7
Linked Version      1.2.7

Directive                       | Local Value       | Master Value
------------------------------------------------------------
zlib.output_compression         | Off               | Off
zlib.output_compression_level   | -1                | -1
zlib.output_handler             | no value          | no value
```

When inspecting the response the site gets from the server then te Content-Encoding header is set as gzip, which I think is strange, since (using my limited DevOps knowledge) I think the info given above should indicate to not use compression.

I would share some code, but I can't pinpoint a part of the code that seems to be the problem, and it seems counter productive to show the entire code for a legacy custom CMS.

Comment: Errors with codes like `AH01386` assigned are errors printed by *Apache httpd* - this is `mod_deflate` complaining about failing to compress something (an error occurring *after* whatever is handling/proxying php ran into an error), not the actual error on the php side. Disabling compression in *httpd* should generally be safe (albeit decreasing performance) and might make error logs about the underlying problem more obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Our website had a similar issue. When viewing the page source retrieved from the server we noticed it was just cut off at some point. We fixed it by adding a [flush()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) call around the cutoff point. Not sure why it was needed and why it worked to be honest.

Comment: My problem is that any and all changes in the code seem to fix this, but after some time it seems to randomly break again. For a personal website this is workable, but after a few times, this becomes increasingly hard to explain to clients.

Answer (score 1):

For me this was caused when the size of the web page was too large and the php.ini value for `output_buffering` was exceeded.  The buffer is flushed early and you only get a partial web page.

You can set a higher limit for `output_buffering` or turn `output_buffering` off to fix this.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering

Be sure to restart php afterwards.  Restarting apache2 didn't load the new php.ini settings for me, needed to restart php separately.

Answer (score 0):

I Had this error today. Disabling PHP notices on top of the page:

```
<?php error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); ?>
```

fixed the problem although I didn't understand why.

Comment: That didn't fix the problem, it merely stopped PHP telling you about it.

Comment: Not exactly: it seems that having a lot of notices (not blocking the PHP script) generate  the "deflating data" error (which stops executing PHP)